# Sencha app watch with scss files included in packages

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-cmd

I am working with Sencha Touch application with different packages with consequent scss files, these files are imported in the app.scss but when the sencha CMD is listening (with the command "sencha app watch") changes are not refreshed itself, I need to reset the command line to get the changes.

What am I doing wrong? or maybe is a bug?

Thanks!!

Comment: What version of CMD are you using?

Comment: Latest version of the Sencha cmd 5

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the package to your app.json file in the requires?

```
"resources": [
    "resources/images",
    "resources/icons",
    "resources/splash",
    "resources/fonts"
],

"ignore": [
    ".svn$"
],

"archivePath": "archive",

"requires": [
     "package-name" <--- Here.
],
```

Comment: Yes, but I have packages with other package like dependency, maybe problem could be here, in the inheritance of packages?

Comment: Could be. Are you using your own packages or Sencha packages like the grid?

Comment: Mmmm nop.. I am not using grids in the app

Comment: Found this on Sencha Cmd Packages http://moduscreate.com/sencha-cmd-packages/ Maybe it will help